# Failed to install PlayOnLinux

Tags: 18.04, playonlinux

I want to install "PlayOnLinux" on Ubuntu 18.04. I opened ***Software and Updates→Other Software→Add***. Then I typed

```
deb http ://deb.playonlinux.com/ubuntu bionic main
```

but it shows some errors:

[image: Error message]

---

Error message details:

```
E:The repository 'https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu ubuntu Release' does not have a Release file., 
W:Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default., 
W:See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details., 
W:An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. 
  GPG error: http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release: 
     The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG 1397BC53640DB551 Google Inc. (Linux Packages Signing Authority) <linux-packages-keymaster@google.com>, 
E:The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/sssup/sssup-ppa/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file., 
W:Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default., 
W:See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details., 
E:The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
```

the following are all my repositories:

[image]

[image]

[image]

How do I solve these errors?

Comment: playonlinux might be a little bit of an outdated solution as it stands. why exactly do you want it? can't lutris ( https://lutris.net/ ) do what you want PlayOnLinux to do?

Comment: i want to play army men RTS :(

Comment: also what distibution are you on exactly 18.04.2? 18.10? other? could you unfold Details error message and see what it says?

Comment: do you have that game on steam?

Comment: im using ubuntu 18.04 LTS
the details error messege:
E:The repository 'http://deb.playonlinux.com ubuntu Release' does not have a Release file., W:Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.,

Comment: W:See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details., E:The repository 'http://deb.playonlinux.com/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file., W:Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default., W:See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details., E:The repository

Comment: do you own that game on Steam?

Comment: yup but its paid

Comment: no...........................................

Comment: well that's unfortunate, that would have been an easy solution. Steam allows you to play all games windows/mac regardless, on linux (it uses wine under the hood)

Comment: I'm also going to add the lutris solution to my answer, but as for POL, Zeiss Ikon found the problem with your command and geve you the solution.

Comment: as for what ikon said it didnt work too :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although PlayOnLinux is already available in official repositories of Ubuntu which can be installed using:

```
sudo apt install playonlinux
```

But if you still want to install from PlayOnLinux's repository, here is what I observed.

After looking at the [repository information for bionic](http://deb.playonlinux.com/playonlinux_bionic.list) availabe on [official site](http://deb.playonlinux.com/), it looks like you added wrong repository (with extra "*ubuntu*"). Modify the repository you've added using "***Edit***" button after clicking on repository in ***Software and Updates→Other Software***.

After that remove "*ubuntu*" from "**URI**" so that it looks like:

[image]

Now open a terminal and run:

```
sudo apt update
```

If you get an error like:

```
Err:1 http://deb.playonlinux.com bionic InRelease                              
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY <some key value>
```

Add that key using:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys <key value>
```

Then try `sudo apt update` again.

---

**Update April 13, 2019**:

It seems you've issues with multiple repositories. We'll correct them one by one.

1. **For `https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu ubuntu Release`**:

   It seems this repository information is wrong. Look at the entry number 6 and 7 in your first screenshot. Repositories don't include version number, i.e. "*18.04 LTS*" but rather their respective codenames, i.e. "*bionic*". So, it's better to delete those entries. Also, according to your question you are using bionic but in your first screenshot it seems you've added repository information of cosmic. So, it's better to edit them and replace "*cosmic*" with "*bionic*". Otherwise, dependency issues might take place.
2. **For `GPG error: http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release`**:

   This was a temporary issue which occurred in all Linux systems as reported on Ask Ubuntu [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/1133199/816190). This issue was from Google's side and is now fixed.
3. **For `http://ppa.launchpad.net/sssup/sssup-ppa/ubuntu bionic Release`**:

   This repository was last updated for Natty (11.04) way back in February 2011. So, it's better to delete it. It's 11<sup>th</sup> entry in first screenshot.
4. **For `http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu bionic Release`**:

   This repository was last updated for Xenial (11.04) way back in 2017. So, it's better to delete it. Precisely it's on 10<sup>th</sup> place in Screenshot 2.

---

***Tips:***

- *I see there are many repositories unchecked. So I assume you don't use them. Try to delete all useless repositories so that less error happens and your other software tab become less cluttered.*
- *If you ever encounter errors like `release file not found`, try to investigate on your own. After all learning is fun **:)**. Just copy the URL before any whitespace and paste it in browser, for example, `http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu` and try to find your distribution under `dists` folder (if present). If your distro is not present, there is some error in repository information.*

Comment: Hey @Terrance, thank you for the comment. I actually prefer leaving key as "key value" since it may happen that at a later stage of time, they change their key. And I don't want my answer to become half obsolete with time just because of that. :)

Comment: I am sorry but I faced the same issue and it was because I didn't use the key value listed on the official website of PlayOnLinux, which is $ wget -q "http://deb.playonlinux.com/public.gpg" -O- | sudo apt-key add -
the key method was a former antique one.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need any external solution to play army men rts on ubuntu or linux in general, just use native steam.

"Steam, you say? but this doesn't solve the problem that this is a windows-only game!"

Actually, yes.

There's a difference between native and non native linux games.

All native linux games can be played on linux as is with steam and as it happens non native games can also be played on linux with steam but thanks to a steam option called "steam play" (which is pretty much essentially wine) that came out relatively recently.

it allows a simplifying of the whole thing. Installing a non linux game with steam comes down essentially to the same easy process you'd have under installing that same game natively, under windows.

So if you're willing to buy the game on steam then,

Simply install steam from : https://store.steampowered.com/about/

this will open up the software center, once it has finished loading, click "install" it will ask for your system password.

then once it is done installing steam, you can run it.

now you may log into steam.

then go into "File"-> "Preferences"-> last tab called "Steam Play", tick the box that says "enable steam play for all titles" then "Ok"

after this steam will ask to restart and after it does you will be able to install and play army men rts in the most hassle-free manner on linux.

If you wish you may play this game with lutris instead :

to do so install lutris (in a terminal) :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:lutris-team/lutris -y && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install lutris -y
```

then you can run it from the start menu. Ideally connect a lutris account.

then go here :

https://lutris.net/games/league-of-legends/ (yes this is for league of legends but we won't be running league of legends with it)

click on the first "install" icon on the page. this should link to your Lutris (you must tell your browser to allow this, when it asks you.)

Let the installer start but when it starts downloading league of legens, close it.

Use the runspace it created, by right-click "browse files" drag and drop the army men rts inside that runspace then right click "execute with" find the install.exe and run it and it should install.

then once you're finished you can edit the rest of the League of legends runner to turn it into a army men rts runner, you must change the run file path to that or you army men rts exe and you can change the name and the icon also.

Comment: ok i will try that and tell u the news, thanks :D

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there may be a stray space in your command line.

```
deb http ://deb.playonlinux.com/ubuntu bionic main
```

Try removing the space immediately before the colon, like this:

```
deb http://deb.playonlinux.com/ubuntu bionic main
```

Comment: that didnt work :(