# apt-update problem for https://ocean.surfshark.com/debian stretch InRelease

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, ppa

I am facing a problem upgrading from 18.04 to 20.04 - while running `apt-get update` I am getting

```
Err:2 https://ocean.surfshark.com/debian stretch InRelease            
 The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG 1DB7590E83C8F643
 Surfshark package maintainer <admin@surfshark.com>
W: GPG error: https://ocean.surfshark.com/debian stretch InRelease:
  The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG 1DB7590E83C8F643
  Surfshark package maintainer <admin@surfshark.com>
E: The repository 'https://ocean.surfshark.com/debian stretch InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is
  therefore disabled by default. 
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Though surfshark didn't even get installed properly and is broken. After some searching I tried various ways to fix it but they didn't work for me as I couldn't get any updated PPA or keys for surfshark.

Comment: Remove the ppa from the sources list.

Comment: but from searching I got that it is dangerous to delete from source list as in the future it won't get updated or check any software from that source

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG 1397BC53640DB551](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1133199/the-following-signatures-were-invalid-expkeysig-1397bc53640db551)

Comment: there they said to do nothing until any official word comes out from admin. but I can't wait till then and being stopped from upgrading my ubuntu version. I would ratherchoose to uninstall the problemetic package and update+upgrade. I told this in the solution.

Answer (score 3):

Go to https://support.surfshark.com/hc/en-us/articles/360017418334-How-to-set-up-Surfshark-VPN-on-Linux-

Then follow steps 1 and 2 (Basically you are downloading and running the code to install surfshark).
Note: I am not pasting the steps 1 and 2 because they rely on a link to the most up to date version of surfshark, and this link may change with time.

These steps will update the keys with a valid one.

Then you can "sudo apt update" and you will see that the problem is gone.

Note2: This worked on my Kubuntu 20.10

Comment: For me this worked, too. thanks. Debian 11 x64, Cinnamon

Answer (score 0):

It would solve the problem if the problematic PPA isn't a big deal for you now. The problem is mainly that Surfshark isn't providing updated PPA/key and the previous is expired or the digest algo sha-1 used for that repository is no longer considered safe.

First run `ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d` and find out the Surfshark PPA. As Surfshark is not a big deal for me now, I just ran `dpkg --list` (to find the package name for Surfshark) and the just run `sudo apt-get purge {package-name}`

It solved the problem for me and now I can do `apt-get update`  and `apt-get upgrade`.and if you face problems now of "“The following packages have been kept back ..." then follow ["The following packages have been kept back:" Why and how do I solve it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/601/the-following-packages-have-been-kept-back-why-and-how-do-i-solve-it) which solved the problem for mine

Comment: @Kulfy now no error is showing but it still isn't allowing me to upgrade saying all updates need to be installed first. but apt-get update is showing just fine.

Comment: Are you trying to upgrade to 20.04 from 18.04? Since I assume that's a different issue, I'd encourage you to ask a new question with full error message and code formatting. See [help center](https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting) for details.

Comment: should I edit the title/body? I was actually trying to update then upgrade but ran into these problems

Comment: Well that might change the context of the question and may make your answer invalid/incomplete answer.

Comment: When you run `sudo do-release-upgrade` to upgrade to a newer release, it should automatically disable all PPAs (informing you and asking you to confirm). Presumably the GUI for upgrading does the same thing. So you would not have had this problem if you had tried to upgrade by those methods, in theory. So I think this is really a problem (or possibly a non-problem :) related to upgrading and you should explain in your question how you are/were trying to upgrade. (cc @Kulfy )

Comment: @Zanna IIRC PPAs are disabled when there's no package that is to be updated or kept back.