# Yarn producing GPG Error

Tags: apt, updates, kubuntu, signature

I am trying to update my Kubuntu 22.04 LTS.
This error occurs:

```
7 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian stable InRelease: The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG 23E7166788B63E1E Yarn Packaging <yarn@dan.cx>
W: Failed to fetch https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/dists/stable/InRelease  The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG 23E7166788B63E1E Yarn Packaging <yarn@dan.cx>
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

How to solve this issue?
I completely removed yarn with `sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove yarn`, but seems that I have to edit `source` file and remove all link to yarn repository. How to get rid of the invalid signatures in the system?

Any ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG 1397BC53640DB551](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1133199/the-following-signatures-were-invalid-expkeysig-1397bc53640db551)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list` will resolve the missing dependencies.

This will work only in case if when the yarn is previously to be removed from the system.

Comment: `rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list` is simpler and avoid running `rm -rf …` and erase files by mistake.

Answer (score 2):

Or for using keyrings to avoid apt-key depreciation issues (e.g. Ubuntu 22.04):

```
curl -fsSL https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | sudo gpg --dearmor -o /usr/share/keyrings/yarn.gpg
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | sudo apt-key add -