# MongoDB 3.6 not update on ubuntu on APT error signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG 58712A2291FA4AD5

Tags: mongodb

I am running Ubuntu 22.04 and am trying to install the UniFi Network Server following the directions [here](https://help.ui.com/hc/en-us/articles/220066768-Updating-and-Installing-Self-Hosted-UniFi-Network-Servers-Linux-).

```
root@orac:/home/mike# sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install ca-certificates apt-transport-https
Hit:1 http://nz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:2 http://nz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease              
Hit:3 http://nz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease            
Get:4 https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/npreining:/debian-ubuntu-onedrive/xUbuntu_22.04 ./ InRelease [1,604 B]
Hit:5 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/yannubuntu/boot-repair/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
Fetched 1,604 B in 3s (508 B/s)
Reading package lists... Done
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
ca-certificates is already the newest version (20230311ubuntu0.22.04.1).
ca-certificates set to manually installed.
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  apt-transport-https
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 5 not upgraded.
Need to get 1,510 B of archives.
After this operation, 170 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://nz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe amd64 apt-transport-https all 2.4.11 [1,510 B]
Fetched 1,510 B in 0s (4,899 B/s)               
Requesting to save current system state
Successfully saved as "autozsys_pl49je"
Selecting previously unselected package apt-transport-https.
(Reading database ... 447867 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../apt-transport-https_2.4.11_all.deb ...
Unpacking apt-transport-https (2.4.11) ...
Setting up apt-transport-https (2.4.11) ...
ZSys is adding automatic system snapshot to GRUB menu
root@orac:/home/mike# echo 'deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] https://www.ui.com/downloads/unifi/debian stable ubiquiti' | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/100-ubnt-unifi.list
deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] https://www.ui.com/downloads/unifi/debian stable ubiquiti
root@orac:/home/mike# sudo wget -O /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/unifi-repo.gpg https://dl.ui.com/unifi/unifi-repo.gpg
--2023-12-11 16:46:44--  https://dl.ui.com/unifi/unifi-repo.gpg
Resolving dl.ui.com (dl.ui.com)... 65.9.142.121
Connecting to dl.ui.com (dl.ui.com)|65.9.142.121|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 1196 (1.2K)
Saving to: ‘/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/unifi-repo.gpg’

/etc/apt/trusted.gp 100%[===================>]   1.17K  --.-KB/s    in 0s      

2023-12-11 16:46:44 (1.47 GB/s) - ‘/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/unifi-repo.gpg’ saved [1196/1196]

root@orac:/home/mike# wget -qO - https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-3.6.asc | sudo apt-key add -
Warning: apt-key is deprecated. Manage keyring files in trusted.gpg.d instead (see apt-key(8)).
OK
root@orac:/home/mike# echo "deb https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu bionic/mongodb-org/3.6 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.6.list
deb https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu bionic/mongodb-org/3.6 multiverse
root@orac:/home/mike# sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://nz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:2 http://nz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease              
Hit:3 http://nz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease            
Ign:4 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu bionic/mongodb-org/3.6 InRelease     
Hit:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease               
Get:6 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu bionic/mongodb-org/3.6 Release [2,495 B]
Get:7 https://dl.ui.com/unifi/debian stable InRelease [2,292 B]                
Get:8 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu bionic/mongodb-org/3.6 Release.gpg [801 B]
Ign:8 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu bionic/mongodb-org/3.6 Release.gpg   
Get:9 https://dl.ui.com/unifi/debian stable/ubiquiti amd64 Packages [714 B]
Get:10 https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/npreining:/debian-ubuntu-onedrive/xUbuntu_22.04 ./ InRelease [1,604 B]
Get:11 https://dl.ui.com/unifi/debian stable/ubiquiti arm64 Packages [714 B]
Hit:12 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/yannubuntu/boot-repair/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
W: https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu/dists/bionic/mongodb-org/3.6/Release.gpg: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
W: GPG error: https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu bionic/mongodb-org/3.6 Release: The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG 58712A2291FA4AD5 MongoDB 3.6 Release Signing Key <packaging@mongodb.com>
E: The repository 'https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu bionic/mongodb-org/3.6 Release' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
root@orac:/home/mike# sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install unifi -y
Hit:1 http://nz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:2 http://nz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease              
Hit:3 http://nz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease            
Hit:4 https://dl.ui.com/unifi/debian stable InRelease                          
Ign:5 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu bionic/mongodb-org/3.6 InRelease     
Hit:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease               
Get:7 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu bionic/mongodb-org/3.6 Release [2,495 B]
Get:8 https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/npreining:/debian-ubuntu-onedrive/xUbuntu_22.04 ./ InRelease [1,604 B]
Get:9 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu bionic/mongodb-org/3.6 Release.gpg [801 B]
Hit:10 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/yannubuntu/boot-repair/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Ign:9 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu bionic/mongodb-org/3.6 Release.gpg
Reading package lists... Done
W: https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu/dists/bionic/mongodb-org/3.6/Release.gpg: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
W: GPG error: https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu bionic/mongodb-org/3.6 Release: The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG 58712A2291FA4AD5 MongoDB 3.6 Release Signing Key <packaging@mongodb.com>
E: The repository 'https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu bionic/mongodb-org/3.6 Release' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
root@orac:/home/mike# sudo service unifi status
Unit unifi.service could not be found.
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

I think it is something to do with this:

```
root@orac:/home/mike# apt update
Hit:1 http://nz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:2 http://nz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease                                                                                                     
Hit:3 http://nz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease                                                                                                   
Hit:4 https://dl.ui.com/unifi/debian stable InRelease                                                                                                                 
Hit:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease                                                                                                      
Ign:6 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu bionic/mongodb-org/3.6 InRelease                                                                                    
Get:7 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu bionic/mongodb-org/3.6 Release [2,495 B]                                                      
Get:8 https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/npreining:/debian-ubuntu-onedrive/xUbuntu_22.04 ./ InRelease [1,604 B]
Get:9 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu bionic/mongodb-org/3.6 Release.gpg [801 B]
Ign:9 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu bionic/mongodb-org/3.6 Release.gpg
Hit:10 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/yannubuntu/boot-repair/ubuntu jammy InRelease                                                                                 
Reading package lists... Done                                                                                                                                         
W: https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu/dists/bionic/mongodb-org/3.6/Release.gpg: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
W: GPG error: https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu bionic/mongodb-org/3.6 Release: The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG 58712A2291FA4AD5 MongoDB 3.6 Release Signing Key <packaging@mongodb.com>
E: The repository 'https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu bionic/mongodb-org/3.6 Release' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Why is it saying the signature is invalid?

I tried the solution [here](https://tecadmin.net/expired-key-expkeysig-with-apt/):

```
mike@orac:~$ sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 58712A2291FA4AD5
Warning: apt-key is deprecated. Manage keyring files in trusted.gpg.d instead (see apt-key(8)).
Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.pKHz7AaGfL/gpg.1.sh --keyserver keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 58712A2291FA4AD5
gpg: keyserver receive failed: Server indicated a failure
```

Also tried the solution indicated in the comments section:

```
mike@orac:~$ sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 58712A2291FA4AD5
Warning: apt-key is deprecated. Manage keyring files in trusted.gpg.d instead (see apt-key(8)).
Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.umOksSwsow/gpg.1.sh --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 58712A2291FA4AD5
gpg: key 58712A2291FA4AD5: "MongoDB 3.6 Release Signing Key <packaging@mongodb.com>" 1 new signature
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:         new signatures: 1
mike@orac:~$ sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://nz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:2 http://nz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease                                                                                                                                  
Hit:3 http://nz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease                                                                                                                                                      
Hit:4 https://dl.ui.com/unifi/debian stable InRelease                                                                                                                                                                                         
Ign:5 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu bionic/mongodb-org/3.6 InRelease                                                                                                                                                                    
Hit:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease                                                                                                                              
Get:7 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu bionic/mongodb-org/3.6 Release [2,495 B]                                                      
Get:8 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu bionic/mongodb-org/3.6 Release.gpg [801 B]                   
Get:9 https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/npreining:/debian-ubuntu-onedrive/xUbuntu_22.04 ./ InRelease [1,604 B]
Hit:10 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/yannubuntu/boot-repair/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Ign:8 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu bionic/mongodb-org/3.6 Release.gpg
Reading package lists... Done
W: https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu/dists/bionic/mongodb-org/3.6/Release.gpg: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
W: GPG error: https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu bionic/mongodb-org/3.6 Release: The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG 58712A2291FA4AD5 MongoDB 3.6 Release Signing Key <packaging@mongodb.com>
E: The repository 'https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu bionic/mongodb-org/3.6 Release' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: When using the root account, you don't need to use sudo.

Comment: Stop trying to install `ca-certificates`. You succeeded. It's installed.

Comment: Your apt output shows a mixture of 18.04 and 22.04 repositories. Cleaning that up may solve some of your problems.

Comment: Unless Ubuntu regenerates the key on Ubuntu Key Server, I think there is no point of removing and adding the same key again and again.

Comment: Here is this issue topic at MongoDB forum:
https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/mongodb-3-6-ubuntu-release-signing-key-expired-2023-12-09/257081/2

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG 1397BC53640DB551](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1133199/the-following-signatures-were-invalid-expkeysig-1397bc53640db551)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is it saying the signature is in valid?

You are trying to install Ubuntu 18.x components into Ubuntu 22.x as per your output:

```
https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu bionic/mongodb-org/3.6 Release: The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG 58712A2291FA4AD5 MongoDB 3.6 Release Signing Key <packaging@mongodb.com>
```

You need to use Ubuntu 22.x repo to install mongodb instead of Ubuntu 18.x

Additionally, having done a similar exercise to install UniFi Network Server elsewhere, installing UniFi Network Server on Ubuntu was problematic. The solution was to use a pure Debian 12 headless server, then use the 'glennr.nl' scripts as per the UniFi forums to install the software correctly on Debian.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the key expired on 9th of December 2023 on Ubuntu [Key Server](https://keyserver.ubuntu.com/pks/lookup?op=vindex&search=0x58712a2291fa4ad5) for Mongo 3.6,

```
sig  58712a2291fa4ad5 2018-12-10T16:51:38Z 2023-12-09T16:51:02Z
```

Comment: Is there a way to forcefully ignore the error and install anyway?